# Why does assembly binding fail in my project?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am working on an Azure function project in a Class Library project that targets `.NET Standard 2.0`.
I am using the following assemblies, shown below.  Beside each one, I've included its dependency requirement of the version of `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs`.

```
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />  Azure.Webjobs needed: >=3.0.5
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" /> Azure.Webjobs needed: >=3.0.14
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.2" /> Azure.Webjobs needed: >=3.0.2
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2" /> Azure.Webjobs needed: >=3.0.16
```

I have installed `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs` **v3.0.22** which (seemingly) satisfies all the above requirements.
Yet when I run my application repeatedly, the runtime alternates between the following errors:

```
Could not load file or assembly **'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
Version=3.0.14.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
does not match the assembly reference.  Source Error:

Calling assembly : **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions,
Version=3.0.6.0**,
```

And this one:

```
Could not load file or assembly '**Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
Version=3.0.5.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80131040)

SCalling assembly : **Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions,
Version=1.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f655f4c90a0eae19.
```

Why is the runtime trying to bind to these lower versions of `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs`?  Why not just use v.3.0.22 which satisfies the requirements listed in Nuget for `Webjobs.Extensions` and `Functions.Extensions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some other assembly that is using the old version of Host, try to add the binding redirect to your config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.14.0" newVersion="3.0.22.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: @syvatis.Iviv can you confirm which config file to use for this with a .NET Standard 2.0 Class library project?  The csproj file?  Or the nuget.config file?  There's no web.config in this project.

Comment: @syvatis.Iviv your recommended solution ultimately works.  The web.config file in my startup project, which isn't the project with the dependency problem, was an effective place to write the redirect.